# How can I print the length of words stored in a string array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to get the **length** of the **words** which I have stored in a **string array**.First,I specify the number of words in an array using '**n**'(input from user), then I take inputs from the user of the '**n**' words they want to store. After that, I wish to print the length of a word.

Here is the code....

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"enter no"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    string A[n];

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         cin>>A[i];
    }
    cout<<strlen(A[2])<<endl;
}
```

For example,
if inputs are:

```
3
leonardo
tom
brad
```

(They are written in separate lines)

then output should be :

```
4
```

which is length of `brad`.

But I get a strange error while execution of this code. **Please suggest a way to do this , while taking inputs from the user in separate lines**

Comment: What error are you having? Is there a reason why you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: `strlen(A[2])` should be `A[2].size()`. `strlen` is not for use with `std::string`.

Comment: You have couple of problems with your short programs... First of all [C++ doesn't have variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Secondly, the [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) function is an old C library function which only handle C null-terminated strings, a.k.a. `char*` type strings, not `std::string` objects.

Comment: @ShadowMitia They are using `std::string`, but `<cstring>` and `using namespace std;` makes it a bit confusing. No idea why the header is included instead of `<string>` though

Comment: I find it really hard to believe that this code compiled at all. Did you mean compiler errors?

Comment: @Lala5th Good catch, but this make things more confusing for me...

Comment: error messages look strange at first. It takes some practice to read them, but actually they typically contain a whole lot of information and sometimes hints on how to fix them. If you don't understand it you should still include it in the question so others can explain it

Comment: Step one should be to get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the basics. Your mix of C and C++ with VLAs on top suggests to me that you are learning from a bad source, maybe from coding competitions.

Comment: For everyone asking why I used <cstring> ? Sorry it was from a previous code that I was trying for that I have edited my question, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cin>>n;
string A[n];
```

The size of an array must be known at compile-time. Variable-length arrays (VLA) are not supported in C++ (also some compilers do as an extension). Use a container with dynamic allocation instead, like `std::vector`.

```
std::cin >> n;    
std::vector<std::string> A(n);
```

And use `A[2].size()` instead of `strlen(A[2])`.

Comment: Thanks  I used A[2].size() instead of strlen(A[2]) and the code works fine with no errors.Do you still think that I should use vectors instead of strings?

Comment: Calling `resize` isn't needed, just pass the size when defining `A`: `std::vector<std::string> A(n);`

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit. Any reason why you don't use `std::vector<std::string> A(n);`?

Comment: You mean a vector instead of C array? Absolutely. Right now your code only just works "by accident".

Comment: @AbhinavPipil -- it's not about vectors instead of strings; it's about using a vector to hold a collection of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
cout << strlen(A[2].c_str());
```

And, for this to work, you also need `#include<string.h>`.

There are two more ways to perform the same function without including any additional header file.

1st method:

```
cout << A[2].size();
```

2nd method:

```
cout << A[2].length();
```